# Performing an operation during enumeration

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection like this:

```
IEnumerable<Query> queries;
```

I am searching for the ones contained in keys of a dictionary and I want to do something on matching value.I know this is possible:

```
(from query in queries
where _metadata.ContainsKey(query.Value)
select query).ToList().ForEach(result=>_metadata[result.Value].AddQuery(result));
```

I wonder if I could make it simpler by calling AddQuery() in matching query enumerations. Query is immutable, so it should not break it.It should be something like this.

```
from query in queries
where _metadata.ContainsKey(query.Value)
//do something like _metadata[query.Value].AddQuery(query)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
foreach (var query = queries.Where(q => _metadata.ContainsKey(query.Value)))
{
    _metadata[query.Value].AddQuery(query)
}
```

You *can* provide lambdas to Select, Where etc which have side-effects - but it's generally a bad idea; LINQ queries are meant to be stateless, ideally - you should be able to iterate over the query multiple times with no problems. Here, we've clearly separated the side-effect (adding a query to `_metadata`) from the query.

Note that the above code still works slightly differently to your original though, due to the way `Where` is executed - each new query will be added *before the remaining `Where` predicates are executed*. In other words, although your query itself is side-effect free, the side-effect you're introducing has an impact on the query.

Comment: AddQuery() method has nothing to do with dictionary keys. It just adds query to a collection of queries(dictionary value). Would it still be a side effect?

Comment: @Ufuk: If calling `AddQuery` doesn't affect `ContainsKey`, that's good. It's still a side-effect, but that's what you *want*. The important thing is that it's a side-effect which doesn't interfere with the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, *pseudocode*:

```
queries.ForEach(query=> {
    if(_metadata.ContainsKey(query.Value))
           //do somethign ... 
});
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If this is not list, consider @Jon's solution => just `foreach` loop

Comment: You got your variable-names mixed up.

Comment: Queries is not a list.I can't call ForEach. I should get the contained values first.

Comment: @Ufuk as there is alredy pretty good solution of Jon on foreach loop, I edit my answer.